jsPDF doc.save() generate pdf includes image in pdf is working fine but using doc.output() string image part generate as junk
doc.addImage(this.image, 'JPEG', 75, 15,57,23);
doc.text(20, 100, 'Subject : Notification');
doc.save('Test.pdf'); 

above code is working fine generated PDF string below, downloaded properly in local
save pdf string
doc.addImage(this.image, 'JPEG', 75, 15,57,23);
doc.text(20, 100, 'Subject : Notification');
this.GenPDF = doc.output();

above code the image part render as junk in pdf file - generated PDF string below, attached pdf file image is not rendered but all the text value render properly, image is not visible in attached pdf
doc.output pdf string
can you please help what is the issue or what is the different between doc.save() outcome and doc.output() outcome--> i have to pass this raw output string to external system and attach the pdf to the reference record
expecting doc.output() string image part should render properly in pdf attached in external record

I have passed the doc.output() --> String rawpdf result string to apex class and in apex method     public static void createpdf (String rawpdf, String recid){ System.debug('RawPDF: '+ rawpdf);     Blob pdfBlob = Blob.valueof(rawpdf);
system.debug('pdfblob:'+ pdfBlob);     ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(    Title='NewGenPDF',  PathOnClient ='NewGenPDF.pdf',    VersionData = pdfBlob,
origin = 'C'    );         Insert(cv); --> here this content file pdf file in reference record all the text and the table in pdf are render properly but image part is looks broken

Hi K J, thank you , if i send the doc.output('blob') from LWC Js to apex class - apex method input parameter is not recognized, so i have passed the PDF string doc.output() to apex method, I will check more in convert String to Blob in Apex class --> Blob pdfBlob = Blob.valueof(rawpdf);

Hi K J, I have checked the doc.Output() -- >string received in Apex class input parameter, then i convert raw string to base 64 and convert this base 64 values to PDF, i can't see the image in the PDF but all other content like text and table are rendered properly, do you have any idea

Hi K J, I have checked the doc.output() -> outcome string in browser console - <<
/Type /XObject/Subtype /Image/Width 284/Height 177/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 8029/Filter /DCTDecode


stream
ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿÛ��  - even in the browser console before sending to Apex - the outcome of doc.output() image sting is not match with the - below is the actual string that working well <<
/Type /XObject/Subtype /Image/Width 284/Height 177/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 8029/Filter /DCTDecode
stream
�JFIF�������� --> outcome of doc.save()



so can please help me here, when we use doc.save() outcome is differ from doc.output() outcome.
